# Cannot install many Python packages with one Docker RUN command

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pip, dockerfile

I can install apt packages using one single Docker RUN command like:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \              
    gcc \                                                                   
    build-essential \                                                       
    zlib1g-dev \                                                            
    glade \                                                                 
    python3-dev \                                                           
    python3-pip \                                                           
    python3-setuptools \                                                    
    pkg-config \                                                            
    libglib2.0-dev \                                                        
    libgirepository1.0-dev \                                                
    libcairo2-dev \                                                         
    gir1.2-gtk-3.0 \
```

However I cannot do the same using Python pip within the Docker RUN command like:

```
RUN pip3 install \
    wheel \
    pycairo \
    PyGObject \
    requests \
    pyinstaller
```

Ending with error:

```
Collecting pyinstaller (from -r /tmp/requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b0/e6/e5760666896739115b0e4538a42cdd895215581618ec885ad043dd35ee57/pyinstaller-4.10.tar.gz (2.7MB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Error: Building wheels requires the 'wheel' package. Please `pip install wheel` then try again.
```

Why?

Despite I can do this:

```
RUN pip3 install wheel                                                         
RUN pip3 install pycairo                                                       
RUN pip3 install PyGObject                                                     
RUN pip3 install requests                                                      
RUN pip3 install pyinstaller
```

Still wish to understand why it cannot be done within ONE Docker RUN pip install command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with combined install

```
RUN pip3 install \
    wheel \
    pycairo \
    PyGObject \
    requests \
    pyinstaller
```

is that `pip` doesn't fully install packages until all listed packages are processed and there're packages that require `wheel` to be already fully installed. First install `wheel` separately, then everything else:

```
RUN pip3 install wheel
RUN pip3 install \
    pycairo \
    PyGObject \
    requests \
    pyinstaller
```

`wheel` is a special package — it's required to install other packages.

Comment: is the error will happen if you try to run "pip3 install wheel pycairo PyGObject requests pyinstaller" on local machine? I mean even on local computer you have to install wheel and others separately?

Comment: @Azii Yes. `wheel` is a very special, it must be installed first.

Comment: Is it correct to say that "pip3 install  -r requirements" could only resolve packages that have no dependency of any other in the list? I removed wheel from requirements.txt but still got the same error on PyGObject (that has dependency on pycairo), but then separating pycairo solved the problem

Comment: @Azii No. Most dependencies can be installed without relying on one another during installation. There're 3 kind of dependencies — build-time dependencies, install-time and run-time. Most dependencies are run-time and can be freely listed in `requirements.txt`. But build-time dependencies must be installed first, before any other package. `pip`, `setuptools` and `wheel` are such special dependencies. Yet another one is `Cython` (when it's used).

Comment: @Azii Glad to be helpful!

Comment: @Azii It came to me there is yet another special case — `numpy`. Most of the time it's just a run-time dependency one can list in `requirements.txt`. But it's written in C/C++/Fortran and exports an API to get compilation config (compiler flags and include directories). Some underdeveloped packages import `numpy` in their `setup.py` and don't provide binary wheels. In that rare case `numpy` becomes build-time dependency and must be installed first.